MongoDB error, running a mern stack project
I am trying to run node server/importData.js but it is showing error. i already connected code with mongodb database using env. still error is showing.

node server/importData.js node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051   throw err;   ^  Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\SwipTory\server\importData.js'     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

I am expecting the data:import part in server when running npm run
